# Not getting all result in parse using laravel 5.1 and php parse sdk with find() method

Tags: php, laravel, parse-platform, laravel-5.1

Hi guys i have my application which uses the parse as my backend database, and i have a problem in get all the data coming from the parse,

when ever this method fire only one row will return.

```
$object_todo = new ParseQuery('TodoClass');
        $todos = $object_todo->find();
        foreach ($todos as $todo) {
            $result = $todo;
        }
        return $result->_encode();
```

Am i missing something to get all records from parse,

P.S i tried to dd($todos) //var_dump();die(); it spitted all result.
Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing Parse API i can see that you are assigning each $todo into a $result without doing anything with it.This means that at the end of the foreach $result will have only the last todo.
If you are on latest php you could just do

```
$result[] = todo;
```

If you are not you will need to init the array outside of the foreach and then

```
array_push($result, $todo);
```